# Bluetooth "falsely" connecting to device

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

When pressing on the device in the list of devices available in the Bluetooth menu, it either doesn't connect or it **sometimes** "falsely" connects, meaning that it appears in Ubuntu to have connected, but it did not if I check the other device. (device is not connected). Tried restarting Bluetooth service, no success. Maybe I can somehow "hard-reset" the Bluetooth service? I can provide any logs if requested.

Edit: Updated from 20.04 to 20.10, no result.

Edit: sudo tail -f /var/log/kern.log prints:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout

Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing

Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
```

Edit: when trying to connect via bluetoothctl to speaker, I get:

```
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Comment: What is the device you are trying to connect?

Comment: A speaker, but nothing works.

Comment: @David added some more logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply powering off the pc and turning off and on the power supply did the trick!